# How to reload KieContainer?

Tags: java, spring-boot, drools, kie

I am using the Drools 7.73.0 version for our rule management. The requirement is, we store rules in MySQL as a String. We need to load drl rules from MySQL at a specific interval and we need to refresh KieContainer so that it will start validating new rules.
How to reload KieContainer?

Comment: Your DBA will hate you for storing your rules in a database as strings. It's a performance nightmare. Highly recommend moving to a different approach.

Comment: Once the server would start, all the rules will be available to spring context. For every update of a rule, I just need to reload the rules again to kiecontainer.

Comment: Doesn't change the fact that storing text blobs in a database is highly inefficient and your DBA will not be able to optimize for performance. I do wonder if maybe you have an XY problem ...

Answer (score 3):

Ideally you would publish a new KIE API `ReleaseId` KJAR to a Maven repository every time you need to refresh the overall system.

This would allow you to trace the releases, and use the `KieScanner` in association with the different KJAR being published.

If that is not possible, a less recommendable path, you could consider creating a `KieModule` programmatically with your file contents, something [explained in the documentation and example](https://docs.drools.org/8.29.0.Final/drools-docs/docs-website/drools/KIE/index.html#_programmatically_build_a_simple_kiemodule_with_defaults).

Something ~like:

```
KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
KieRepository kr = ks.getRepository();
KieFileSystem kfs = ks.newKieFileSystem();

kfs.write("src/main/resources/org/kie/example5/HAL5.drl", getRule());

KieBuilder kb = ks.newKieBuilder(kfs);

kb.buildAll(); // kieModule is automatically deployed to KieRepository if successfully built.
if (kb.getResults().hasMessages(Level.ERROR)) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Build Errors:\n" + kb.getResults().toString());
}

KieContainer kContainer = ks.newKieContainer(kr.getDefaultReleaseId());
```

then you would use `KieContainer#updateToVersion` to programmatically trigger a manual update of the container per the [Javadoc](https://docs.drools.org/8.29.0.Final/kie-api-javadoc/org/kie/api/runtime/KieContainer.html#updateToVersion(org.kie.api.builder.ReleaseId)).

Something ~like:

```java
kContainer.updateToVersion( newModuleReleaseId );
```

Comment: For OP's use case, the optimal solution would be to have some sort of process which publishes a new kjar every interval. That way the service would be able to pull the new kjar when it becomes available, and the artifact is preserved for auditing/reproducibility/debugging purposes. It would also handle some rudimentary validation without causing issues with the running service as well, which is a bonus.